# Flutter showBarModalBottomSheet with active background for searchbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `showBarModalBottomSheet` throughout my app, all the time with the background grayed out so that it is inactive. However, I want to use it to show search hits like google maps does it. For this I have my search bar on top and its event listener pops up the `showBarModalBottomSheet` on text change of the search bar.

Now, the search bar becomes hidden under the grayed out layer, so I am not sure how to "activate" the background for this particular view so that I can keep editing the search bar text.

Which of the parameters would that be?
https://pub.dev/documentation/modal_bottom_sheet/latest/modal_bottom_sheet/showBarModalBottomSheet.html
To me it seems as if it was not possible.
This is my current prototype code to show the modal:

```
void searchCallback(String searchValue){
    showBarModalBottomSheet(
      isDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 0),
              child: Material(
                child: SafeArea(
                  top: false,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        const Row(
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Text('Placeholder?'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Divider()
                      ]
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
      )
    );
  }
```